# Autofilling spreadsheet row when date is (ex: today) and value "name" is in that row

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, google-query-language

i'm trying to get some info from another spreadsheet using IMPORTRANGE and VLOOKUP.

I have created a new spreadsheet and named it after a date of the month ex: 21 February
In another sheet, i have a big list of dates where each date has a phone number, a name and a persone who this "contact" has been asigned.

I want that whenever this list of dates is updated, they get sent into different spreadsheets.

Example:
[image]

In the other spreadsheet i want to automaticall fill in the sheet based on the DATE which on the example above is 21.

So, Toms sheet should look like
[image]

Any idea what formule can i use combined with IMPORTRANGE?

Best regards.

Comment: Consider providing a sample of the spreadsheets you are working on, visually clarifying the expected output.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rPNURZPfD9qe8Y5xvLclprwQK5uT1pWSo5Qi9Lfco8o/edit?usp=sharing I created the results above but for some reason the tables got deleted... @player0

Comment: added a file where i have created the table and how i want the out come, but it should not be in the same spreadsheet. @Iamblichus

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: @player0 were you able to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, run IMPORTRANGE as standalone formula to connect your sheets by allowing access

next, try in Tom sheet:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("url_or_id_of_sheet", "sheet_name!A:D")}, 
 "select Col2,Col3 
   where Col4 = 'Tom' 
     and Col1 date = '"&TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", )
```

Comment: ps: it doesn't have to be the current date, i just took it as an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("ID OF SHEET", "SHEET_NAME!A:I")}, "select Col3,Col4 where Col8 = 'Tom' and Col2 = 'date as text'",)
```

This worked for me as where i have placed date, it's a text cell not a date.

Thanks to @player0